Sustainsys.Saml2 No cookie preserving state from the request was found
I've run into an issue using Sustainsys.Saml2 library to authenticate to MS Entra using Saml2. This question seems to have been asked many times. I've looked through many online posts with the same issues as me on here and Microsoft and still can't find a solution. I'm either not doing something specific to .NET Framework 4.7.2 or haven't truly found my issue.
I'm getting the following error:
Received message _a80178a3-d538-4b8e-a538-5fbbef823aca contains unexpected InResponseTo "iddbc74838186f4f58a236105450827f37". No cookie preserving state from the request was found so the message was not expected to have an InResponseTo attribute. This error typically occurs if the cookie set when doing SP-initiated sign on have been lost.

Here's what I got:

A .NET Framework 4.7.2 WebForms application
Running app on local IIS
A trusted SSL certificate for the host domain (local.abc.com); we've tried issuing certificate to *.abc.com and local.abc.com and no success (yes we moved them to the Trusted Root Authentication Authority; we even had the same certificate used on our production servers installed on our dev machines just to test
I've added an intercept script to update the SameSite value(s) to nothing or "Unspecified" for the cookies using ht following articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/csharpwebforms
No cookie error in chrome. UnexpectedInResponseToException

This solution works just fine on production, which runs an Azure App Service, but does not work on our local machines.
Thanks for your help.

"I've added an intercept script to update the SameSite value(s) to nothing or Unspecified" - Neither of those are valid. You want SameSite=None.

Interesting, I'll try it. On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite#using-samesite-in-aspnet-472-and-48 it shows as a valid value <httpCookies sameSite="[Strict|Lax|None|Unspecified]" requireSSL="[true|false]" />

Unspecified is not a valid value for the text of the Set-Cookie HTTP header; but it is a magic value used by ASP.NET to denote not rendering the SameSite= parameter at all - which is confusing.

Understood. Thanks. Using None does not change the outcome.

What browser are you using? Are you using Private/Incognito mode? Does your browser's DevTools console give you any messages or warnings about cookies being dropped? Are you using any <iframe> elements to pass cookies around?

Not using <iframe>, tried latest Chrome, Firefox, Safari. I'll check DevTools and I haven't tried Private, but I have been clearing the cookies each time. I'll check back when I try it.

@Dai No luck on using private mode and no console messages.

We are starting to believe IT IS a certificate issue. All of the sudden it started working today (we haven't rebooted at all, just left things open overnight). We work on Macs running Win10 on VM Fusion. So far it's working on Chrome in the VM, but not on Safari (host machine) even when we have set the certificate to Always Trust and Safari shows Valid Certificate.

After testing many different things, I tried to focus on certificates. I was using wildcard certificates like this: *.abc.com. Even with the certificate trusted it was not working.
Once I created a new certificate for local.abc.com and trusted those, everything worked just fine.
My next venture, if possible, how can I use a wildcard certificate? We have several websites with subdomains of our abc.com domain, that we'd prefer working with just one vs 10 or 20.
